# Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional with $\dim V > 0$, and suppose $W$ is infinite-dimensional. Prove that $L(V, W)$ is infinite-dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Since $W$ is infinite-dimensional, there exists a sequence $w_1,w_2,...$ that is linearly independent. We name this list $A$.

Suppose $a_1 \in V$ is in $V$'s basis list.

Define $T_i : V \rightarrow W$ $$T_i(a_1)=w_i \; \; \; \; \; \forall i \in \{i \in \mathbb{N}: w_i \in A \}$$

(Let $c_i \in \mathbb{F}$.)

Now, consider $c_1 T_1 (a_1)+...+c_m T_m (a_1)=0$

$$c_1 T_1 (a_1)+...+c_m T_m (a_1)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow c_1 w_1+...+c_m w_m=0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow c_1=...=c_m=0$$
Thus, the list $T_1,...,T_m$ is linearly independent.
Also, since $W$ is infinite-dimensional, $m$ can be any natural number.

We know a linearly independent list can be extended to a basis.
i.e. $m \leq \dim L(V,W)$.

Since $m$ can be any natural number, $\dim L(V,W)=\infty .$

Hence, $L(V,W)$ is infinite-dimensional vector space. $\blacksquare $

Is this proof valid?

Comment: Yes, the proof is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this proof is valid. The one thing I would say is that your definition of $T_i$ is somewhat incomplete. You could say,

> For each $i \in \Bbb{N}$, choose any linear $T_i : V \to W$ such that $T_i(a_1) = w_i$.

Or, even better, you could say,

> For each $i \in \Bbb{N}$, define a linear map $T_i : V \to W$ by its action on the basis $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ of $V$, so that $T_i(a_k) = w_i$ for all $k = 1, \ldots, n$.

This is mostly a stylistic point. I get the impression from what you've written that you understand that you can construct linear maps from bases, but technically what you've written down as the definition of $T_i$ is incomplete.

Comment: I really like your first definition. This makes my understanding much clearer. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: It's certainly more elegant than the second in presentation. The second is a bit more explicit, but the first makes it very clear how you're constructing $T_i$ (or at least, the rules by which you could construct $T_i$). I would also choose the first, myself.